# How to validate a relation property in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

### What I have

I have a `Room` model with a has many relation to `Reservation`. `Room` has a property `is_open` indicating that the given room is available.

### Goal

I would like to be able to validate in the `rules` function of a `FormRequest` that a room is available when I store a new reservation based on the `is_open` property.

### What I tried

The validated data is in an array so the rule key needs to be this: `data.room_id`. I know that `exists` can validate something in the database but I don't know how its syntax works. Also how can I validate a property of a relation?

```php
class ReservationStoreRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'data.room_id' => 'exists:' // what goes here?
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

```php
public function rules() {
  return [
    'data.room_id' => [
      Rule::exists('rooms', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_open', 1);
      })
    ]
  ];
}
```

### Validating with `exists`

There is [documentation on the `exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists) rule but it is really concise. Lets see what the commands in the docs actually mean. The point of this rule is that it can validate the existence of a field in a table in your db given by some criteria. For example, when you save a reservation you can validate that the room you are reserving is exists in the database.

#### Basic usage

```php
'size' => 'exists:rooms'
```

This will check the `rooms` table if there is an entry where the `size` column contains the value that is the value under validation (in this case the corresponding value of key `size` which is `large`). This results in the following SQL query:

```sql
select count(*) as aggregate from `rooms` where `size` = "large";
```

#### Specifying a custom column name

In the previous section the validated column's name comes from the key of the validated property ('size'). You might want to give a different column name because you are validating a column that is named differently from your data's key (e.g. 'size' is stored in the 'category' column) another case is that your `rooms` table's primary key is just `id` instead of `room_id` like in the validated data. In your case the validated data's key is `data.room_id` but you would like to check the `id` column of `rooms`. You can specify the column's name separated by a comma:

```php
'data.room_id' => 'exists:rooms,id'
```

This will check the `rooms` table if there is an entry where the `id` column contains the value under validation resulting in the following SQL query:

```sql
select count(*) as aggregate from `rooms` where `id` = 4;
```

#### Specify a custom column name with extra clauses

If you need to further filter the results you can use the [`Illuminate\Validation\Rule`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Validation/Rule.html) class. You pass the table and column name (the second being optional just like in the basic usage section) and in an anonymous function add the extra clauses to the query. You can use every input data in the request, just retrieve it with `$this->input('propertyName')` or `$this->all()` then processing it by hand:

```php
'data.room_id' => [
  Rule::exists('rooms', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
    $query
      ->where('is_open', 1);
      ->where('size', $this->input('data.size'));
  })
]
```

The resulting SQL query is this:

```sql
select count(*) as aggregate from `rooms` where `id` = 4 and (`is_open` = 1 and `size` = large);
```

The available clauses in the `$query` variable are `where`, `whereNot`, `whereNull`, `whereNotNull`, `whereIn` and `whereNotIn`. Check out the [`Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Exists` class docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Exists.html#method_whereNot).